# Remove duplicates in excel 2013 and concate all from third coulmn where there were duplicates

Tags: excel, concatenation

I am reviewing large amounts of data pointing out where there are inconsistencies. See the below example starting data:

[image]

Here is the result I am aiming for:

[image]

The Query I have so far:

```
=IF(AND(Sheet2!A2=Sheet2!A3,Sheet2!B2=Sheet2!B3),Sheet2!A2&Sheet2!B2&Sheet2!C2,"no match")
```

How can I Concate all results where Coulmn A and B match, remove duplicates but also concate all results in column C where the duplicates would have been into that one row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are open to a VBA solution, this can easily be achieved with the following code.
The code assumes data is in the column A:C with row1 being the header row.
The output will be written in column E:G. You can change the output location as per your requirement.
If required the output can also be written back in column A:C in the desired format.

```
Sub SummarizeData()
Dim i As Long
Dim x, y, dict, it
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'clearing columns E:G before writing the output
Columns("E:G").ClearContents
x = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For i = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
    If dict.exists(x(i, 1) & ";" & x(i, 2)) Then
        dict.Item(x(i, 1) & ";" & x(i, 2)) = dict.Item(x(i, 1) & ";" & x(i, 2)) & ", " & x(i, 3)
    Else
        dict.Item(x(i, 1) & ";" & x(i, 2)) = x(i, 3)
    End If
Next i
i = 1
ReDim y(1 To dict.Count, 1 To 3)
For Each it In dict.keys
    y(i, 1) = Split(it, ";")(0)
    y(i, 2) = Split(it, ";")(1)
    y(i, 3) = dict.Item(it)
    i = i + 1
Next it
'Writing the output in columns E:G
Range("E1").Resize(dict.Count, 3).Value = y
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```